# Does >> has any significance in C?

Tags: c, conditional-statements

I am beginner in C programming language, recently I have read about Logics. Does expression like `x >> 1` has any significance in C?

```
if (x >> 1) {
    printf("%d", x);
}
```

Comment: @Akshay remember it is Saturday night in some [parts of the world](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0c1cfax.aspx).

Comment: Have you tried using `>>` on a known value and then print the result? What happened?

Answer (score 1):

The `>>` operator is the right shift operator.  It takes the value on the left side and shitfs each bit by the number of bits on the right hand side.

For example, if the binary value of a variable is `00110` (6), shifting right by 1 results in `00011` (3).  Similarly, shifting `01001` (9) right by 2 results in `00010` (2).  So for unsigned integer values, it effectively divides by a power of 2 rounded down.

If the left operand of `>>` is a signed integer and has a negative value, the result is implementation defined (section 6.5.7 of the current [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)).  On most common desktop implementations which use 2's complement representation of negative numbers, a `1` bit will be shifted in from the left in this case to preserve the sign of the variable.

So `11111011` as a signed value (-5) right shifted by 1 results in `11111101` (-3).  As is the case with positive values, this effectively divides by a power of 2 rounded down.

In the example given, the variable `x` is shifted to the right by 1.  Then the value of that expression is evaluated in a boolean context, meaning it is checked to see whether or not it is zero.  If the resulting value is non-zero, then the `printf` command is executed.

Comment: Note the example `11111011` as a signed value (-5) would be `signed char`. Shifting that right is implementation-defined behaviour.